# Monotouch and BasicHttpBinding with TransferMode="StreamedRequest"

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

Can I use WCF service with TransferMode="StreamedRequest" in Monotouch application?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the mono source it seems that StreamedRequest is supported using the IRequestChannel interface, and this type is included in the version of WCF that ships with MonoTouch.

However the only way to know if it works....is to test it against the subset of WCF that ships with MonoTouch. The simplest way to do this would be to first verify that you can create a valid generic ChannelFactory using the IRequestChannel interface. And then proceed to actually bind to a service that implements this TransferMode.

This might be a good use case for utilizing [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit) to reproduce the associated tests here:

```
https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/Test/System.ServiceModel.Channels
```